# GANs: Why does iterative gradient descent sometimes optimise $\min_G \max_D V(D,G)$ and sometimes $\max_D \min_G V(D,G)$?

Tags: objective-functions, generative-adversarial-networks, gradient-descent, numerical-algorithms

For the following minimax equation for generative adversarial networks (GANs),

$$\min_G \max_D V(D,G) = \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{x}\sim p_{data}(\boldsymbol{x})}[\log D(\boldsymbol{x})] + \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{z}\sim p_{\boldsymbol{z}}(\boldsymbol{z})}[\log(1 - D(G(\boldsymbol{z}))]  $$

Goodfellow mentions in his paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf, page 3, 1st paragraph under equation 1) that in practice this minimax game is implemented iteratively (algorithm 1 in the paper).

In one of his tutorials ([1:31:52 - 1:33:16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGYYEUSm-0Q&t=5512s&ab_channel=StevenVanVaerenbergh)) he mentions that $\min_G \max_D V(D,G)$ is desirable, whereas $\max_D \min_G  V(D,G)$ leads to mode collapse. Iterative gradient descent can "sometimes act" like the former, and sometimes like the latter.

I am confused about how the iterative method can sometimes act like min-max or max-min. What about gradient descent causes the change in behavior?